# RestTemplate.postForObject and server side @RequestBody

Tags: spring, rest

Is is mandatory for the object sent through RestTemplate.postForObject to match exactly the type of object on the server side?  I have written server a server side API that accepts a base class of the specific objects being sent through RestTemplate, and I'm receiving a 400 Bad Response from server.  If the class of object is the same on both sides, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is mandatory to match because resttemplate converts your object to specified representation(eg: into XMl or JSON) and at the serverside @requestbody unmarshalls to specifed object so if you are using baseclass, your root element changes making it impossible to unmarshal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems like the mapper could reflect on the "real" type and allow a more abstract design.